# Team Project Repo Activity Log

Tags: azure-devops

Inside of Azure DevOps or VSTS, if I go to the home page of my Team Project, I see an activity section on the right that shows the total number of commits over the last 7 days.  You can change the time frame from 7 days to 1 day or 30 days but that's all you can do.

Is there another location to see that graph where it's more interactive?  How else can I see the 7 day history for all repos in this team project?  Possibly with the ability to drill down by commit author.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Contributions Graph Extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.contributions) help you with all type of filtering with different repos, [image]commits etc.,